# Creating dictionary entries in Python using dot notation when key is an iterator

Tags: python, dictionary

I've subclassed `dict` like so:

```
class ObjectiveDict(dict):

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self:
            return self[name]
        else:
            raise AttributeError("No such attribute: " + name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        """
        IMPORTANT NOTICE: when "name" is an iterator of an iterable, will not work, must use [] syntax
        """
        self[name] = value

    def __delattr__(self, name):
        if name in self:
            del self[name]
        else:
            raise AttributeError("No such attribute: " + name)
```

Now when I have something like:

```
objd = ObjectiveDict({'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3})
objd.d = 4
```

This works well, outputting:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

But, if I have a list of keys that I want to append to the `objd`, let's say with a default value, it creates a key using the name I used for the iterator to iterate over the list, i.e.:

```
keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
for k in keys:
    objd.k = None
```

It outputs:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'k': None}
```

I know I can overcome this using the `objd[k] = None` or using `setattr` method but I wanted to understand why is it that when I use the dot notation the `__setattr__` method of my `ObjectiveDict` gets the iterator as a string? And is there a way to patch up my code so it works with the dot notation?

Comment: Because that's how `.` operator works, the attribute name is passed as a string to `__setattr__`. In your case it is going to be `'k'`.

Comment: You need to use `for k in keys: setattr(objd, k, None)`; this is never going to work with dot notation. As @AshwiniChaudhary says, `foo.bar = 'baz'` is translated to `foo.__setattr__('bar', 'baz')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Python is coherent.

In the first case you were happy with `objd.d = 4`, translated to `objd['d'] = 4`. But it could have been :

```
d = 'e'
objd.d = 4
```

and you would still have got `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}` (hopefully **not** `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'e': 4}`).

So when you write in the second case:

```
keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
for k in keys:
    objd.k = None
```

you just repeat `objd.k = None`, which is translated to `objd['k'] = None`, three times.

There no way in dot notation to use the *value* of the name, you can only use the name itself.

You could make it work by using :

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    self[eval(name)] = value
```

but I really urge you **not to do that** ! In first case you would get :

```
d = 'e'
objd.d = 4
objd
```

=> output : `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'e': 4}` !